# Mocked object can not be accessed directly

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, jestjs

In Jest, I have the following test code. I import `NativeModules`:

```
import { NativeModules } from 'react-native';
```

Then, before each test, I add to it my own object:

```
 beforeEach(() => {
    NativeModules.Dispatcher = {
        methodA: jest.fn(),
        methodB: jest.fn(),
        methodC: jest.fn()
    };
 });
```

In the source code that I am testing, I import `NativeModules`:

```
import { NativeModules } from 'react-native';
```

And I reference my mocked object

```
class ClassThatIsTested {

   someMethod(parameter) {
      NativeModules.Dispatcher.methodA(parameter);
      //some other code
  }

}
```

This works fine. However, if I try to reference the mocked object directly:

```
import { NativeModules } from 'react-native';
const { Dispatcher } = NativeModules;
class ClassThatIsTested {

   someMethod(parameter) {
     Dispatcher.methodA(parameter);
      //some other code
  }

}
```

It fails:

```
Dispatcher.methodA is not a function
```

If I print `Dispatcher`, I get `undefined`.

Why is this happening? Why can I not access the mocked object directly?

Answer (score 0):

```
import NativeModules from 'react-native';
```

is incorrect, you need to [import the named export `NativeModules`](http://facebook.github.io/react-native/releases/0.49/docs/native-modules-ios.html), rather than the default export:

```
import {NativeModules} from 'react-native';
```

Comment: I'm really sorry, I've copied my code incorrectly. Actually, I do use `import {NativeModules} from 'react-native';`.